# How to download docutils pages with django?

Tags: django, django-admin, docutils

I'd like to download all my documentation done with docutils into a some format (html, pdf etc) is there a way to do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Here's an example:
    `response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/ms-excel")`
    `response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=excel.xls'`
which will provide an attachment named excel.xls in excel format for you to download